# What is this cast iron skillet with diagonal ribs intended for?

Tags: equipment, cast-iron, cookware, skillet

I'm not actually sure if "skillet" is the right word for this, but it seems close. We got this second hand, so not sure of its origin.

The particular feature that I'm not sure of is the set of diagonal raised 'ribs'. Seems like they would keep the food items from the bottom surface. Is this something like what you would use a wire rack for when baking?

It is 10 x 10 in. (25 x 25 cm) and 1 1/2" deep.

Is this skillet intended for something specific? We're located in the USA if that makes any difference.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are commonly called [grill pans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grill_pan).

[image]

<sub>[Image Source](https://www.amazon.ca/Lodge-P12SGR3-12-Inch-Pro-Logic-Pre-Seasoned/dp/B0001DJVGA)</sub>

With a grill pan you can get an appreciable experience of outdoor grilling indoors, and staying indoors has gotten more and more necessary nowadays due to the pandemic...

The ridges allow juices to flow off the meat so the meat doesn't just sit and boil in them (like what a grill does).

Answer (score 2):

That is a "grill pan" and it is intended to allow food to cook above the grease that it might release, and create grill marks on the food in which it is cooked.  It simulates grilling without the benefit of the juices falling into the fire (which creates the grilled flavors that many of us enjoy).

Comment: Note that this isn't true in British English, where it would be called a "griddle pan" (or occasionally "ridged frying pan") and a "[grill  pan](https://www.espares.co.uk/product/es487929?utm_source=google+shopping&utm_medium=shopping&utm_campaign=google+shopping)" is something you'd use under a grill (that would be called a "broiler" in some countries). I believe some other Commonwealth countries follow the British terminology here.

Comment: The same is true in some regions of the US, though both major us manufacturers of cast iron pans appear to also call them "grill pans."